# Why does foreach not call child class' new method?

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach, polymorphism, parent-child

I am surprised to see the output of the following Console Application in C#:

```
abstract class Shape
{
    public abstract void Draw();
}
class Circle : Shape
{
    public override void Draw()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Drawing Circle");
    }
}
class SpecialCircle : Circle
{
    public new void Draw()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Drawing SpecialCircle");
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Shape[] myShapes = { new Circle(), new SpecialCircle() };
        foreach(Shape s in myShapes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s.GetType());
            s.Draw();
        }
        SpecialCircle scirc = new SpecialCircle();
        scirc.Draw();
    }
}
```

which has the output:

```
CallChildClassMethod.Circle
Drawing Circle
CallChildClassMethod.SpecialCircle
Drawing Circle
Drawing SpecialCircle
Press any key to continue . . .
```

So I wonder why in the foreach-statement it recognizes that the second element of the array is a `SpecialCircle`, yet is uses the method `Draw` from the class `Circle`. Contrary to the behaviour when defining a `SpecialCircle` object outside of an array and a foreach-loop.

Can anyone help me sort this out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because you are using the `new` keyword, if you change it to `override` you will get the behaviour you expect.

`new` doesn't override the implementation in the base class, it hides it. This basically means that when the instance is treated as the base the base implementation will be called and when it's treated as the derived type the derived types implementation will be called.

You can test this by doing

```
SpecialCircle scirc = new SpecialCircle();
scirc.Draw();
Circle circle = scirc;
circle.Draw();
```

This would output

```
Drawing SpecialCircle
Drawing Circle
```

Comment: Thanks! When would I want new then?

Comment: When you want the everything treating the instance as the type of the derived class to call that method, but you want other classes treating it as the base to call the base implementation.

Comment: I think the pragmatic answer is "rarely". Granted, I don't have decades of experience yet, but in the years of experience I DO have so far, I have never ever had any use at all for the `new` keywords ability to hide members.

Comment: @String: A common situation for "new" is illustrated by the design of the `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>` interfaces. Plainly both must have a `GetEnumerator`, and equally plainly, they cannot be compatible because they have different return types. If we wish `IEnumerable<T>` to inherit from `IEnumerable` then we should indicate that the colliding member is *intended* to collide. By omitting "new" the compiler reasons that the collision may be an unintended accident, and warns you.

Answer (score 0):

When using `new` you have to invoke it through a reference to the `SpecialCircle` class.

When you call outside of the loop, you have a reference to `SpecialCircle` which causes the `new` method to be called.